# Single-handle kitchen sink having low pressure on one side at a time

Tags: water-pressure

I had a plumber replace a two-handle sink faucet with a single-handle one.  But the water pressure on the hot was just a trickle, but was normal on the cold side.  The plumber was puzzled by this, so he switched the hot and cold lines below the deck and, surprise, the normal flow was now on the hot side, and there was a trickle on the cold.  We thought the faucet was faulty, so I got a new one.  But that one had the exact same problem.  Now the plumber is telling me the problem is with the shut-off valves, but that is not making a lot of sense to me, both because everything was fine with the former two-handle faucet and because I don't understand how this problem could be explained by the shut-off valves when the hot and cold both seem to be working, albeit at different times.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like a bad cartridge in the faucet if there is one. Contact the faucet manufacturer and ask for help as ... Explain what you have been through.

Comment: Try opening/closing the hot shutoff repeatedly while both taps are fully open. The shutoff might have a bit of gunk restricting flow. (Don’t forget to clean the aerator screen afterwards.)

Comment: I don't understand how it could be the shutoff valve, when both the hot and cold work properly, one at a time.  (Again, either the hot or cold has low pressure, depending on how the lines are configured, not just one.)